# Ubuntu 22.04 shared internet connection with multiple interfaces

Tags: networking, network-manager, 22.04, dhcp, routing

I use **Lubuntu 22.04 LTS with Cinnamon** desktop to be precise.

I have one network device with a single interface on my motherboard.

**enp5s0** is the one connected with my ISP-router, with fixed **IP 192.168.1.19/24**.

I have another network device with 4 interfaces:

[image]

**I would like to use this second network device as a router.
How should I proceed?**

For now, I could share only to one interface by changing the method and editing the IP:

[image: shared enp7s4f0 interface]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my solution by looking for the netboot server setup:

1. I edited every single interface from the second device to mach with enp7f4s0 *(same IP too)*.
   [image: interfaces_IP_config]
2. I installed dnsmasq:

`sudo apt install dnsmasq`

3. I created a config file like suggested on [Ubuntu.com about netboot](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/netboot-amd64) configuration.

`touch /etc/dnsmasq.d/pxe.conf`

4. I edited the **pxe.conf** file as follow:

   `interface=enp5s0,lo`

   `bind-interfaces`

   `dhcp-range=enp7s4f0,192.168.2.2,192.168.2.10`

   `dhcp-range=enp7s4f1,192.168.2.11,192.168.2.20`

   `dhcp-range=enp8s6f0,192.168.2.21,192.168.2.30`

   `dhcp-range=enp8s6f1,192.168.2.31,192.168.2.40`

   `dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0`

   `dhcp-match=set:efi-x86_64,option:client-arch,7`

   `dhcp-boot=tag:efi-x86_64,bootx64.efi`

   `enable-tftp`

   `tftp-root=/srv/tftp`

Now my internet connection is shared on every interface of my second ethernet device.

```
● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-06-18 07:19:38 CEST; 35min ago
   Main PID: 3458 (dnsmasq)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18871)
     Memory: 656.0K
        CPU: 19ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/dnsmasq.service
             └─3458 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsmasq -7 /etc/dnsmasq.d,.dpkg-dist,.dpkg-old,.dpkg-new --local-service --trust-anchor=.,20326,8,2,e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409>

Jun 18 07:19:38 lubuton dnsmasq-dhcp[3458]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.2.31 -- 192.168.2.40, lease time 1h
Jun 18 07:19:38 lubuton dnsmasq-dhcp[3458]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.2.21 -- 192.168.2.30, lease time 1h
Jun 18 07:19:38 lubuton dnsmasq-dhcp[3458]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.2.11 -- 192.168.2.20, lease time 1h
Jun 18 07:19:38 lubuton dnsmasq-dhcp[3458]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.2.2 -- 192.168.2.10, lease time 1h
Jun 18 07:19:38 lubuton dnsmasq-dhcp[3458]: DHCP, sockets bound exclusively to interface enp5s0
Jun 18 07:19:38 lubuton dnsmasq-tftp[3458]: TFTP root is /srv/tftp
Jun 18 07:19:38 lubuton dnsmasq[3458]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Jun 18 07:19:38 lubuton dnsmasq[3458]: using nameserver 127.0.0.53#53
Jun 18 07:19:38 lubuton dnsmasq[3458]: read /etc/hosts - 5 addresses
Jun 18 07:19:38 lubuton systemd[1]: Started dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
```

My last change to the dnsmasq configuration did also work:

```
interface=enp5s0,lo
bind-interfaces
log-dhcp
dhcp-host=pxe.home.lan,192.168.2.1
dhcp-range=192.168.2.2,192.168.2.40
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/srv/tftp
```